# Why won't text-indent work?

Tags: css

I want to indent the first line of the text in each paragraph

```
p3 {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 50px;
  font-family: Helvetica, serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: What is p3? That is not a valid html selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the issue with your non-valid selector, I will asume you meant `p`.

You need to add the text-indent to the wrapper element, not the paragraph itself.

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  font-family: Helvetica, serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

div {
  text-indent: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**if** `p3` is `class` (`class="p3"`)  so use `.p3` in css

```
.p3 {
display: inline;
text-indent: 50px;
font-family: Helvetica, serif;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 100;
margin-top: 40px;
}
```

**if** `p3` is `id` (`id="p3"`) so use `#p3` in css

```
#p3 {
display: inline;
text-indent: 50px;
font-family: Helvetica, serif;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 100;
margin-top: 40px;
}
```

I reccomand you to learn more about `selector` in css::https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: tell me for more help